# One to many relationship to CSV PHP array issues where data isnt all the same

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, laravel

I'm using laravel as a framework but really this is just a PHP / data issue.

I have a table called servers and it will have a serverid and each row is a server. I then have a facts table which has a row for every 'fact'. Now, this isn't always the same, for example

```
Server A might have CPU, MEMORY, ENVIRONMENT, LOCATION
Server B might have CPU, OS TYPE, LOCATION
```

My struggle is I want to export this to CSV, I can get the header row but I'm trying to get each row to be uniformed and line up (and obviously.. the data doesn't match neatly on every line), where it doesn't I want a empty record.

So (I've used  where it would be empty):

```
SERVERID, CPU, MEMORY, ENVIRONMENT, LOCATION, OSTYPE
SERVERA,  1,    2048,  PRODUCTION,  DC1,      <BLANK>
SERVERB,  1,    2048,  <BLANK>,     DC2,      WINDOWS
```

A code example ( I think its the array_merge area where each entity in the array isn't alike in terms of keys)

```
foreach ($serverarray as $servers) {
    $servers = array_filter($servers, function($v) { return $v != "rawfilename"; });
    $serverfact = $this->get_facts_by_serverid($servers['serverid']);
    $serverresultfull[] = array_merge($servers,$serverfact);   
}

$file = $this->create_csv($serverresultfull);


public function create_csv($data)
{
    $userid = Auth::user()->id;
    
    $file = uniqid($userid,true);
    $filename = "$file.csv";
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k=>$v) {
            $headerv[]= $k;
        }
    }
 
    fputcsv($fp, array_unique($headerv)); 
    foreach ($data as $key=>$fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);  
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return $file;

}
```

Any help greatly appreciated, even a point in the right direction would really help...

Comment: You should probably set a default array with all the necessary keys first, values empty - and then merge that with the specific data array you get back from the `get_facts_by_serverid` call.

Comment: Yes this worked!! Didn’t realise an array merge will keep the keys on unmatched keys too!